# whole array printing instead of a single value within it

Tags: c, arrays

I need to be able to read in a word from a file one at a time and then be able to sort the text into a struct to track how many times words have been repeated however whenever I try to point to a specific word in the file I'm getting the whole file value instead of the specific word I'm trying to retrieve. apologies if the solution is simple, I still struggle with the different types of pointers and file commands

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *inputFilename;
char *outputFilename;

char inputText[5000];
char outputText[5000];

int inputFlag;
int outputFlag;

int readfile(char **data){

    FILE *input;
    input = fopen(inputFilename, "rb");
    int len = sizeof(*input);

    printf("input length is %d\n", sizeof(char));

    //First value is number of integers
    int size;
    fread(&size, sizeof(char), 0, input);

    //allocate memory for that number of values 
    *data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);

    //Read in rest of data 
    fread(*data, sizeof(char), size, input);

    //return size 
    printf("size is %d\n", size);
    return size;    
}

int valueSearch(char *vData, int argCount, char **argv){

    for(int argLoop = 0; argLoop < argCount; argLoop++){    

        //If vData is detected then the next argument is the input file name 
        if(strcmp(argv[argLoop], vData) == 0){

            return argLoop + 1;

        } 
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    char *data;

    inputFlag = valueSearch("-i", argc, argv);

    printf("input flag is %d\n", inputFlag);

    inputFilename = argv[inputFlag];

    if(inputFlag == 0){

        printf("Please enter the text you would like to sort: ");

        fgets(inputText, 5000, stdin);

    }
    else{

        int size = readfile(&data);

    }

    int i = 0;

    //Value that should be placed into struct 
    printf("readfile value 0:\n%s\n", data[i]);

    free(data);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are you able to compile it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your last `printf` uses `%s` instead of `%c`. `%s` treats the argument as a pointer to a string (char array), and prints each byte until it encounters a byte of 0. You want `%c`, which prints out a single char.

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do. I need to be able to select a whole word from the file then be able to compare it to ones saved in the counting struct im going to add like I have done with the inputFilename using the valueSearch function and argv[inputFlag] on line 58. essentially im trying to read from my file the same as i would the argv

Answer (score 0):

Use `%c` instead of `%s` because `%s` is a identifier of string and that will print whole string.

```
 printf("readfile value 0:\n%c\n", data[i]);
```

Hopefully it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to become familiar with compiling with *compiler warnings enabled*, and then do not accept code until it compiles without warning or error.

You invoke *Undefined Behavior* on line `19` and again on line `76` by using improper *conversion specifiers* for `int` (instead of `long int` - line `19`) and again as already noted on line `76` where you use `%s` instead of `%c`.

Further, you do not include `string.h` which is required for the use of `strcmp` on line `41`. There is no declaration for `strcmp` so your compiler makes a guess at an implicit declaration.

You will also find unused variables `len` and `size` in your code. (lines `17` and `69`, respectively).

All of these problems are readily apparent from your compiler output if you compile with `-Wall -Wextra` (and if wanted `-pedantic`) on `gcc`, with `-Weverything` on clang, or `/Wall` with VS (`cl.exe`) (you may want `/W3` on VS as `/Wall` means all (and you will have to individually disable a handful of warning there with `/wdXXXX` where `XXXX` is the code for the warning you wish to disable).

While not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you, but failing to follow it can lead to the wrong first impression in some circles.

Moral of the story -- (1) enable compiler warnings, and (2) do not accept code until it compiles cleanly -- without warning. Letting your compiler help you write better code will eliminate a large percentage of the errors you spend time chasing `:)`